# I don't understand this function(options)

Tags: jquery

I don't understand this, if I have image slider and image preloader

```
jQuery.fn.awShowcase = function(options);  //slider
$.fn.preloader = function(options); // preloader
```

They don't work on the same page because the function is the same?

Comment: They should work just fine...

Comment: Are you suggesting that because their formal parameters have the same name, that makes them the same function or something?

Comment: Are you asking a question or reporting your observed result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what functions are the same  because neither of them are.

When writing jQuery you can either refer to library with  `jQuery` or `$` because they set to each other internally. The `fn` is pointing to jQuery's namespace (think of it as `obj.foo = {) In that example obj is`$`and foo is`fn`.

The last part is the actual plugin name. Both `awShowcase` and `preloader` are both assign to whats called anonymous functions. So when you call `$('selector').awShowcase()` or `$('selector').preloader()`, that anonymous function is called.

Since `awShowcase` and `preloader` are not the same there should be no conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

They will work fine, your defining two custom jQuery functions, they operate independently via

```
$('selector').awShowcase(options);

$('selector').preloader(options);
```